# Visual Studio 2017 cannot launch IIS Express 10.0 on Windows 10.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, iis-10

I have installed Visual Studio Community Edition on Windows 10 with IIS Express 10.0

When I created a new web project using provided template of Asp.NET Core 1.1, project did not launch in any browser , In event viewer I get following error.

Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/TESTAPPLICATION' with physical root 'D:\Projects\Aspnet Core1.0\TestApplication\TestApplication\' failed to start process with commandline '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" -debug -p "C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin\dotnet.exe" -a "exec \"D:\Projects\Aspnet Core1.0\TestApplication\TestApplication\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\TestApplication.dll\"" -pidFile "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8A1D.tmp" -wd "D:\Projects\Aspnet Core1.0\TestApplication\TestApplication"', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 0.

Note in my other machine with Windows 8.1 there is no issue with same configurations and projects run successfully there in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1982 this is a known issue. but no response there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was My machine already had Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with updates side by side of Visual Studio 2017.

I removed it and then I tried to remove all individual program beginning with word Core (SDK and runtime etc).

Then I remove .NET Core Command-Line Interface (CLI) Tools after that Visual Studio 2017 worked like a charm.